# sequential numbering in SHAREPOINT 365 List without using ID

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like to create a flow to get sequential reference numbers but, I don´t want to use the Unique Identifier (ID). I already have a power automate flow using ID but as the ID is a read-online field, it cannot be modified so, when an entry from the SP list is deleted, the sequence numbers suffer a jump (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5, >> if the last entry is deleted, the number 5, in the next entry the flow will add a number 6 entry instead of overwriting number 5 so, I will get a jump in my sequence 1,2,3,4,6)

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually: Find the item in the list with the highest reference number and increment that by 1.

Actions you can use for that

- get list items - use the advanced setting to order the list by the reference number in descending order. Use the "Order by" field with `<FieldName> desc`.
- with the First() function you can get the first item returned by the previous step, which, based on the sort order, should be the one with the highest reference number. You can use a variable with this expression:

`first(outputs('MyItems')?['body/value'])?['Reference']`

`MyItems` is the name of the step I used to load the list. My column is called `Reference`.

- Next, use an Increment Variable action to increment the variable, then use that in a new list item.

[image]

Here is the result

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: How about if the item is deleted how this flow will again assign the number ? example 1,2,3,4,5  and if Row number 3 is deleted , the above flow will not reset as per what user is asking in the question.

Comment: The OP talks about the LAST number getting deleted. The SharePoint ID will not repeat the deleted ID, but my approach will repeat the reference number if it was the last one. As asked for in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this piece of knowledge!! really appreciated

Comment: Please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. That is how you can say thank you around here.